# javascript replace text in multiple HTML files with other text

Tags: html, file, replace, find

I would like create a javascript that automatically find and replace a text variables with another ones in multiple HTML files, for instance:

text to search (located as is in HTML files):

%%LNG_SyndicateNewProducts%% 
%%LNG_SyndicateNewProductsAtom%% 
%%LNG_SyndicateNewProductsIntro%% 
%%LNG_SyndicateNewProductsRSS%% 
%%LNG_SyndicateNews%% 
%%LNG_SyndicateNewsAtom%%
etc.

text to replace (located all in a file):

Produse  noi
Ultimele % Produse Noi (Atom)
Ultimele produse încărcate conţin ultimele %s produse adăugate pe %.
Ultimele %s Produse Noi (RSS)
Noutăţi
etc.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks,
Cornel

Comment: What have you tried? Lots of people here will help, but most have real jobs where they get paid to DO this work for people.

Comment: Or you could just use `sed`?